# Why does datatransfer between sockets takes lot of time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, client-server

I have implemented a web based client-server system. The goal is to request for an image file to server, through the socket.

Here is my code at client end. [embedded Javascript code]

```
 <a id="downloadLnk" download="new.jpeg" style="color:red">Download as image</a>

 var socket = io("ipaddress");
socket.on("image", function(info) {
if (info.image) {
var end1 = new Date().getTime();
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = end1; 
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + info.buffer;  
}

function download() {
this.href = img.src;
};
downloadLnk.addEventListener('click', download, false);
});
```

And this is the code at server side: [node.js server, express module, fs module]

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
var start1 = new Date().getTime();
console.log(start1);

fs.readFile(__dirname + '/aorta-high512.jpg', function(err, buf){
socket.emit('image', { image: true, buffer: buf.toString('base64') });
});   
});
```

I am transferring a 512x512 resolution image of size 88KB and it is taking approximately one second. Similarly for a 259KB file it takes around 1.2s and 2MB file it takes 2.5s. I do not understand why it is taking so much time? 
I checked the bandwidth avalable, internet speed of my network in speedtest.net. The download speed is 95.97Mbps and upload speed is 23.30Mbps.

Could you please let me know, why the transfer time of data is so slow? Is there any other method to transfer data in a faster way? I definitely know that 96Mbps is the bandwidth available but still to test I downloaded a 100Mb pdf file from internet it took approximately 12-14s. Looking at this I atleast expect faster transfer of data at the rate of atleast 2-3 Mbps.

Comment: It takes time (and more space) to convert to base64 and back. Did you try just using the raw binary data? Socket.io supports sending/receiving binary data.

Comment: Thank You. Yes, I tried sending binary raw buffer to client, it saved lot of time. Now my 1.5Mb file takes around 150ms to transfer. However, when the file is received at client end, i download the file i.e save it using download() function by setting img.src to href. By this method I am unableto save the files larger than 1.7 Mb, do not know what is the issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're probably hitting a browser limit. If so, you could workaround that by stacking multiple img tags and splitting the data up between them to reduce the base64 length for each image. If you're wanting to actually download it to disk instead of displaying in the DOM, then you'll probably have to download it from the server via a separate HTTP GET.

Comment: Yes, I have earlier tried HTTP GET. Yes I can download any file size from server. However, my main goal to is determine the time taken by data to transfer from server to client, in this case it is download time. And I couldn"t find any way to calculate this download time. So I opted socket method to calculate time.

Comment: @mscdex : Could you please rewrite the comment as answer here? The solution said by you has solved and it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.IO supports sending/receiving binary data, so taking advantage of that will allow you to avoid expensive encoding of data.

Secondly, when generating/using a data URL in browsers you have to be careful about the URL length. Many browsers impose various limits on the maximum size of such data URLs. One possible workaround to this (not including serving the image directly via HTTP GET) could include having the server split the image into a smaller set of images, which you then use with stacked `img` tags to give the appearance of a single image.